# Recursion for my program?

Tags: python, recursion

What this code does is it prints out all the n of a kind combinations that can be played. Where `S = Spades`, `H = Hearts`, `D = Diamonds`, and `C = Clubs`. So in this case the hand would produce:

```
[['3H'], ['3H', '3C'], ['3H', '3D'], ['3H', '3C', '3D'], ['3C'], ['3C', '3D'], ['3D'], ['4S'], ['6D'], ['7D'], ['9S']]
```

for all the playable n of a kind combinations.

I was wondering if there is a way for me to do this piece of code in a recursion loop? As it would get tedious to keep re-typing the iteration if there were more than 4 suits in a card deck

```
hand = ['3H', '3C', '3D', '4S', '6D', '7D', '9S']

def generate_plays(sorted_hand_value):
    playable_card = []
    for i in range(len(hand)):  
        playable_card.append([sorted_hand_value[i]]) # appends 1 of a kind to the     playable_cards list

    if i+3 <= (len(hand)-1): #need this restriction of that the interation won't index something that is out of the range of the list

        if sorted_hand_value[i][0] == sorted_hand_value[i+1][0]: #checks if first and second card have the same value
            playable_card.append(list((sorted_hand_value[i],sorted_hand_value[i+1]))) #appends 2 of a kind to the playable_card list

            if sorted_hand_value[i][0] == sorted_hand_value[i+2][0]:
                playable_card.append(list((sorted_hand_value[i],sorted_hand_value[i+2]))) #checks if first and third card have the same value
                playable_card.append(list((sorted_hand_value[i],sorted_hand_value[i+1],sorted_hand_value[i+2]))) #appends 3 of a kind to the playable_card list 

                if sorted_hand_value[i][0] == sorted_hand_value[i+3][0]:
                    playable_card.append(list((sorted_hand_value[i],sorted_hand_value[i+3])))#checks if first and fourth card have the same value
                    playable_card.append(list((sorted_hand_value[i],sorted_hand_value[i+1],sorted_hand_value[i+2],sorted_hand_value[i+3]))) #appends 4 of a kind to the playable_card list

    elif i+2 <= (len(hand)-1):

        if sorted_hand_value[i][0] == sorted_hand_value[i+1][0]:
            playable_card.append(list((sorted_hand_value[i],sorted_hand_value[i+1])))

            if sorted_hand_value[i][0] == sorted_hand_value[i+2][0]:
                playable_card.append(list((sorted_hand[i],sorted_hand[i+2])))
                playable_card.append(list((sorted_hand_value[i],sorted_hand_value[i+1],sorted_hand_value[i+2])))

    elif i+1 <= (len(hand)-1):

        if sorted_hand_value[i][0] == sorted_hand_value[i+1][0]:
            playable_card.append(list((sorted_hand_value[i],sorted_hand_value[i+1])))
return playable_card

print generate_plays(hand) #
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"n of a kind"*? This usually relates to face value (i.e. three tens) rather than suit.

Comment: what do you mean by "can be played"? what are the rules of the game?

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import combinations

hand = ['3H', '3C', '3D', '4S', '6D', '7D', '9S']

def all_combos(cards):
    # return all non-empty combinations in ascending order by number of items
    for howmany in range(1, len(cards)+1):
        for combo in combinations(cards, howmany):
            yield combo

def n_of_a_kind(hand):
    # get suits for each value
    # ie {'3': ['3H', '3C', '3D'], '4': ['4S'], '6': ['6D'], '7': ['7D'], '9': ['9S']}
    value_suits = defaultdict(list)
    for card in hand:
        value_suits[card[0]].append(card)
    # get all possible non-empty combinations for each value
    return [combo for cards in value_suits.values() for combo in all_combos(cards)]
```

then

```
print(n_of_a_kind(hand))
```

gives

```
[('4S',), ('7D',), ('6D',), ('9S',), ('3H',), ('3C',), ('3D',), ('3H', '3C'), ('3H', '3D'), ('3C', '3D'), ('3H', '3C', '3D')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use groupby to select groups of cards which have the same value (sorting them first, to make sure they're all together), and then a powerset recipe to generate all the n-of-a-kinds (excluding the empty sets).

```
from itertools import groupby, combinations

def kinds(cards):
    for _, cs in groupby(sorted(cards), lambda x: x[0]):
        s = list(cs)
        for r in xrange(1, len(s)+1):
            for p in combinations(s, r):
                yield list(p)

print list(kinds(['3H', '3C', '3D', '4S', '6D', '7D', '9S']))
```

The output is:

```
[['3C'], ['3D'], ['3H'], ['3C', '3D'], ['3C', '3H'], ['3D', '3H'],
 ['3C', '3D', '3H'], ['4S'], ['6D'], ['7D'], ['9S']]
```